# Flutter endless scrolling HTTP JSON with refresh indicator

Tags: flutter

I'm quite new to Flutter and i'm working on an app. I was trying to find an tutorial on how to get a list with HTTP json contents that shows like the first 10 of it and when you keep scrolling down it will start to show you more. Also i would love to have an refresh indicator on it.

Anyone has a good tutorial or github repo for this?

Thanks in advance, 
Greetings

Comment: https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/infinite_listview might do that

Comment: Here is a good tutorial: https://appdividend.com/2019/01/01/flutter-listview-example-displaying-dynamic-contents-tutorial/

Comment: Found a great tutorial yesterday, thanks for the help. I would recommend this if you are looking for the same thing as i was. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WESR99r5GKE

Comment: https://youtu.be/yIZFo5tGRvs